# while loop giving unexpected results

Tags: javascript

I have  this code:

```
var totalMoneyForCredit=150;

// Your Current Billing from Shop
var moneySpent=0;

// Prices of Phones
var samsungPrice=30;
var sonyPrice=22;
var nokiaPrice=22;

// Asseorices for mobile
var charger=5;
var headset=10;


// Ask user for Purchasing Which mobies
while(totalMoneyForCredit>0){
    var order=prompt("Please enter the mobile you want to Purchase");

    if (order==='sam') {
        moneySpent=moneySpent+samsungPrice;
        totalMoneyForCredit=totalMoneyForCredit-samsungPrice;
        if (moneySpent<totalMoneyForCredit) {
            document.write('<b>' +  'The total money Spent till yet is ' + moneySpent + " and the money remaining in credit card is " + totalMoneyForCredit  + "</br>")
        }
        else if(moneySpent>totalMoneyForCredit)
        {
            document.write('Out of Money!!');
        }
    }
}
alert('You ran out of money!');
```

Now on the third run with sam entered, **it should not say out of money as I still have 60 left after third entry.**

But the result is:

```
The total money spent till yet is 30 and the money remaining in credit card is 120
The total money spent till yet is 60 and the money remaining in credit card is 90
Out of Money!
```

here is a snapshot.
[image: Snapshot]
Please tell me where am I doing it wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because on each loop you're **both** increasing `moneySpent` **and** decreasing `totalMoneyForCredit`, so `moneySpent>totalMoneyForCredit` is true as of the third loop (because `90` is greater than `60`). You probably want to do one or the other, not both, or check for `totalMoneyForCredit > 0` instead.

---

Separately: Don't use `document.write` for anything interactive, it'll bite you: If you ever gave the browser a chance to breathe (you don't in that code) and finish parsing the document, the next call to `document.write` would *wipe out* the document and start fresh.

Instead, give yourself a function like this:

```
function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = msg;
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

...and use that.

---

To get a better understanding of the code as it runs, use the debugger built into your browser, which lets you put breakpoints in the code to stop it so you can look at variables; lets you step through statement by statement and see the values of variables at that moment in time; etc. Chrome's [dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging) are *excellent*, but Firefox has half-decent ones built in or you can add the Firebug add-in, and IE's "F12 Developer Tools" are better than nothing.

---

Also strongly recommend putting spaces around your operators, but that's purely a style thing.

Comment: can you recommend a basic javascript debugging tutorial?

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini: I did, above. :-) See the link. Maybe not hyper-basic, but it's pretty clear. I don't know of others, though obviously there are plenty out there I'm sure.

Comment: Thanks T.J  This is great